# MySQL UNIX_TIMESTAMP acting weird

Tags: php, mysql, date

In my database I have a `datetime` field with the following value `2014-07-21 00:00:00`.

When I pull the data I have the line:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) AS `date` ...
```

When I then use PHP date to format it for human reading the following happens:

```
echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s', $row['date']);
// outputs 20/07/2014 23:00:00
```

I don't understand what's doing this.

Comment: Probably timezones and/or daylight savings. Check that your PHP and MySQL timezone settings and configs are the same.

Comment: why don't you use simply `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s')` instead?

Comment: @VMai: because in the object that's loading the data I want it as a timestamp. That way I can control the presentation format with PHP for different scenarios.

Comment: I thought so. Maybe you could edit this restriction into your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a timezone problem. `2014-07-21 00:00:00` will convert to very different UNIX timestamps depending on what timezone the database assumes this time to be in. Conversely, PHP will convert the UNIX timestamp to the human-readable version depending on the timezone set with `date_timezone_default_set`. You'll have to ensure that MySQL's internal timezone setting and PHP's internal timezone setting are identical if you expect the same value to be output.

Comment: Cheers, that sounds about right, I'll accept when the time limits done.

Answer (score 0):

I replicated the same in my database and I got exactly the same value. I cannot say if you and I are in the same timezone, but one thing is sure - according to the documentation  [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)

If UNIX_TIMESTAMP() is called with a date argument, it returns the value of the argument as seconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC

That explains the disparity. 
To solve the problem you can select the date normally and use strtotime in php to convert it to timestamp. As in

```
SELECT date AS `date` ...
echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($row['date']));
```

Hope this helps..cheers!